# Setting global sql_mode in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-mode

I am trying to set `sql_mode` in MySQL but it throws an error.

Command:

```
set global sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLE','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

- Is this not the proper way to set multiple modes?
- What are the advantages of setting session and global modes?
- Which is preferred?

I have different users trying to update the database with different UNC values and instead of setting the session mode to `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`, I though it would make sense to set a *global mode* for this. Does this make sense?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Those errant quotes really bother me ;p. As others said I'm sure, this is definitely not right just because of that.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I resolved it.

the correct mode is :

```
set global sql_mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Comment: WARNING: In our experience this does not retain the setting after a MySQL restart...

Comment: Yes this does not retain settings after restart

Comment: For retaining it after restart for unix, I had to create a ~/.my.cnf file and add [mysqld] sql_mode = "<new mode>" . Hope this helps

Answer (score 274):

BTW, if you set globals in MySQL:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

This will not set it **PERMANENTLY**, and it will revert after every restart.

So you should set this in your config file (e.g. `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in the [mysqld] section), so that the changes remain in effect after MySQL restart:

*Config File: /etc/mysql/my.cnf*

```
[mysqld] 
sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

---

UPDATE: Newer versions of Mysql (e.g. 5.7.8 or above) may require slightly different syntax:

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

*Make sure that there is a dash between `sql-mode` not an underscore, and that modes are in double quotes.*

Always reference the [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) for **your** version to see the [sql-mode options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_sql-mode).

Comment: Thank you, setting in my.cnf did the trick for me.  For those interested, this page tells you what the default sql_modes are in 5.7 and above:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: 5.7 version note up!
That was the problem.

Comment: In an actual web application the second query works. I just added another query after the mysqli connection query. SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
Thanks Chad!

Comment: In `5.7.20`, and for the case of  `mysql.ini`, using an underscore and forgetting the quotes works just fine, like so: `sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`

Answer (score 37):

Setting sql mode permanently using mysql config file.

In my case i have to change file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` as `mysql.conf.d` is included in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. i change this under [mysqld]

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

just removed `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` sql mode cause it was causing issue.

I am using `ubuntu 16.04`, `php 7` and mysql --version give me this `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.13, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

After this change run below commands

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service mysql start
```

Now check sql modes by this query `SELECT @@sql_mode` and you should get modes that you have just set.

Answer (score 29):

For someone who googling this error for MySQL 8.

MySQL 8.0.11 remove the 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' from sql-mode.

> MySQL 5.7: Using GRANT to create users. Instead, use CREATE USER.
>   Following this practice makes the NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER SQL mode
>   immaterial for GRANT statements, so it too is deprecated. MySQL
>   8.0.11: Using GRANT to create users. Instead, use CREATE USER. Following this practice makes the NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER SQL mode
>   immaterial for GRANT statements, so it too is removed.

Taken from [here](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1492#issuecomment-387683159)

So, your `sql_mode` can be like this:

```
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Or if you're using Docker you can add next command to *docker-compose.yml*

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.13
    command: --sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
    ports:
      - 13306:${MYSQL_PORT}
```

Comment: How does this command --sql_mode=STRICT_TRAN... work?

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck because of this line.

Answer (score 18):

Copy to Config File: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf OR /bin/mysql/my.ini`

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
sql-mode=""
```

`MySQL` restart.

Or you can also do

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
```

`MySQL` restart.

Comment: I think it's `sql_mode` instead of `sql-mode`.

Answer (score 6):

For Temporary change use following command

```
set global sql_mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

For permanent change : go to config file /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and add following lines then restart mysql service

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Answer (score 6):

Access the database as the administrator user (root maybe).

Check current SQL_mode

```
mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

To set a new sql_mode, exit the database, create a file

```
nano /etc/mysql/conf.d/<filename>.cnf
```

with your sql_mode content

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Restart Mysql

```
mysql> sudo service mysql stop
mysql> sudo service mysql start
```

We create a file in the folder **/etc/mysql/conf.d/**
because in the main config file **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**
the command is written to include all the settings files from the folder **/etc/mysql/conf.d/**

Answer (score 4):

Check the documentation of [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

**Method 1:**

Check default value of sql_mode:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode //check current value for sql_mode

SET GLOBAL sql_mode = "NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

**Method 2:**

Access phpmyadmin for editing your `sql_mode`

- Login on phpmyadmin and open localhost
- Top on **Variables** present on the top in menu items and search out for **sql mode**
- Click on edit button to modify sql_mode based on your requirements
- Save the changes

[image: sql mode settings in phpmyadmin]

Restart server after executing above things

Answer (score 3):

In my case mysql and ubuntu 18.04

I set it permanently using this command

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Append the line after the configuration. See example highlighted in the image below.

```
sql_mode = ""
```

> Note :*You can also add different modes here, it depends on your need*
> *NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION*

See Available [sql modes  reference](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/) and [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)

[image: adding sql mode]

> Then save.
> After saving you need to restart your mysql service, follow the command below:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have to change file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` change this under [`mysqld`]

Paste this line on [`mysqld`] portion

```
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem where MySQL (5.6.45) wouldn't accept `sql_mode` from any config file.

The solution was to add `init_file = /etc/mysql/mysql-init.sql` to the config file and then execute `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';` in there.

Answer (score 1):

Updating this for users Using MAMP PRO {works with MAMP users too}. Because I seem to have got stuck on finding a solution for this, but people recommended I should edit the `my.cnf` file in the `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf` folder which does not work because it gets reset after every restart of mysql server.

Referring [this document](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/FAQ/MySQL/Where-is-my-my.cnf-file-located/):

> The configuration file “my.cnf” of MySQL can be found here:
> “/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf”. Please note: Editing this file
> does NOT work as it will be overwritten every time MySQL is restarted
> by MAMP PRO with a “my.cnf” file that is created from the MySQL
> template. You must edit this template (menu File > Open Template >
> MySQL (my.cnf) > 5.7.30) to modify the MySQL configuration. Manually
> adding “my.cnf” files to other locations is not recommended. Every
> configuration aspect can be handled with the MySQL template.

Once this is done, add the following in the my.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Restart the Mysql Server. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If someone want to set it only for the current session then use the following command

```
set session sql_mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this in Azure, go to the MySQL resource in the portal, server parameters, search sql_mode. Then open the drop down and remove the selection for the parameter in question. Finally click save.

Answer (score -3):

```
set global sql_mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```