# Setting of sql mode is not working in mysql

Tags: mysql

i am using below query for setting sql mode in database

```
SET @@sql_mode = ''
```

it shows successful, but my database sql_mode is not changed.

help me another way.

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317650/setting-global-sql-mode-in-mysql

Comment: selcet  @@sql_mode

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer .....

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried on both mysql client and SQLFiddle, both works well:

**SQLFiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/52236**

```
mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+-------------------+
| @@sql_mode        |
+-------------------+
| STRICT_ALL_TABLES |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @@sql_mode = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+------------+
| @@sql_mode |
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```