# ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'created_at'

Tags: mysql

When I tried to alter the table it showed the error:

```
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'created_at'
```

I googled for this error but all I found was as if they tried to alter the timestamp so it occurred. However here I am trying to add a new column and I am getting this error:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE investments ADD bank TEXT;
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'created_at'
```

and my table's last two columns are `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Here is my table structure:

[image]

Comment: what are the default values for these columns ?
Can you please share table structure ?

Comment: @Priyanshu i have updated my table structure

Comment: set default value current_timestamp for last two columns.

Comment: Step by step instruction for resolving such problem described in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69733605/2677449

Answer (score 228, accepted):

The problem is because of **sql_modes**.
Please check your current sql_modes by command:

```
show variables like 'sql_mode' ;
```

And remove the sql_mode "**NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE**" to make it work.
This is the default sql_mode in mysql new versions.

You can set sql_mode globally as root by command:

```
set global sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: I know this, but in my server sql_mode showing blank, Still not working, I am using [Server version: 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 - (Ubuntu)]. Any one can have any solution without upgrading server version?

Comment: have you checked by global command ?
and is there nothing in sql_mode for same session ?

Comment: I checked show variables like 'sql_mode' ; and the output is Variable_name|Value = sql_mode|

Comment: So guys, there is no way! OK I am going to upgrade server. Thanks!

Comment: I found a temporary solution ->create trigger and set date field to now()

Comment: This answer shows you how to see the value but not how to change it. For those wondering, this variable is stored in the "my.cnf" file on the server. Changing it there will affect the default so it will be persistent. `SET sql_mode` is temporary.

Comment: This will be useful for this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317650/setting-global-sql-mode-in-mysql

Comment: Didn't work for me with 5.7. Not sure if I had to do it globally or not.

Comment: First check the sql_mode:
Run command: `select @@sql_mode;`
You will get mode list.
Then run `SET sql_mode = '';`
then select you database by run `use database_name`;
then run your code which has error
and at last again run `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';` this has all that option which you get by first command run

Comment: this is not working with MySQL 5.7 , getting this response : ```0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 3135 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.```

Comment: Just an note for XAMPP users like me, you can set this value by opening config for mysql  in the XAMPP console. Open my.ini and search for 'mode'. Edit, save, restart. Yep, noob tip. Meh.

Comment: This doesn't work on newer versions of mariadb either. You can run both queries (non-global and global), then try an import a database. The import will fail.

Comment: Exported a WordPress database with Navicat, and attempted to import to WP Local which uses Adminer and got the error but thankfully in adminer entering the second command in this answer resolves that!

Comment: I had to quit mysql and then restart it for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 135):

Simply, before you run any statements put this in the first line:

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** this statement should be used only in development, not in production.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But only removing date restrictions `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE` only allows us to maintain other security features : `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';`

Comment: For clarification, this statement should be used only in development, not in production.

Comment: I suggest this shouldn't even be used in development, one should fix the problem instead of disabling this.

Answer (score 43):

Try and run the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `investments` 
MODIFY created_at TIMESTAMP 
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
NOT NULL;
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE `investments` 
MODIFY updated_at TIMESTAMP 
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
NOT NULL;
```

The reason you are getting this error is because you are not setting a default value for the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. MySQL is not accepting your command since the values for these columns cannot be null.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Many of the other answers are work-arounds to turn off the error.  In modern MySQL, it is better to set the default value to valid value.

Answer (score 33):

I came across the same error while trying to install a third party database. 
I tried the solution proposed unsuccessfully i.e. 
`SET sql_mode = '';`

Then I tried the command below which worked allowing the database to be installed
`SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';`

Comment: `SET sql_mode = '';` is now deprecated, `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = ''` is OK

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I have a file to import.
So I simply added `SET sql_mode = '';` at the beginning of the file and it works!

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem. Following solved it:

Change:

`recollect_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',`

to:

`recollect_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`

i.e. just remove the quotes around ***CURRENT_TIMESTAMP***.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

For Mysql5.7, login in mysql command line and run the command,

```
mysql> show variables like 'sql_mode' ;
```

It will show that NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE in sql_mode.

[image]

Try to add a line below [mysqld] in your mysql conf file to remove the two option, mine(mysql 5.7 on Ubuntu 16) is /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

[image]

Now restart mysql. It works!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `ttt` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t1` TIMESTAMP  NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `t2` TIMESTAMP  NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `t3` TIMESTAMP  NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `t4` TIMESTAMP  NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

- Because the TIMESTAMP value is stored as Epoch Seconds, the timestamp value '1970-01-01 00:00:00' (UTC) is reserved since the second #0 is used to represent '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.
- In MariaDB 5.5 and before there could only be one TIMESTAMP column per table that had CURRENT_TIMESTAMP defined as its default value. This limit has no longer applied since MariaDB 10.0.

see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/timestamp/

**sample**

```
MariaDB []> insert into ttt (id) VALUES (1),(2),(3);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB []> select * from ttt;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | t1                  | t2                  | t3                  | t4                  |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2000-01-01 12:01:02 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2000-01-01 12:01:02 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  3 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2000-01-01 12:01:02 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
```

Answer (score 5):

Run this query:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

it works for me

Comment: by the way don't need SET time_zone = "+00:00";

Answer (score 4):

Just convert it by this line :

for the new table :

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

---

for Existing Table:

```
Alter ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

---

Source :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in @Bernd Buffen's answer. This is issue with MariaDB 5.5, I simple upgrade MariaDB 5.5 to MariaDB 10.1 and issue resolved.

Here Steps to upgrade MariaDB 5.5 into MariaDB 10.1 at CentOS 7 *(64-Bit)*

1. Add following lines to MariaDB repo.

   `nano /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo`
   and paste the following lines.

> [mariadb]
>      name = MariaDB
>      baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos7-amd64
>      gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
>      gpgcheck=1

2. Stop MariaDB, if already running
    `service mariadb stop`
3. Perform update

   `yum update`
4. Starting MariaDB & Performing Upgrade

   `service mariadb start`

   `mysql_upgrade`

Everything Done.

Check MariaDB version: `mysql -V`

---

**NOTE**: Please always take backup of Database(s) before performing upgrades. Data can be lost if upgrade failed or something went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

1. First, check existing mode(s) are using the following command in your terminal:

   `$ mysql -u root -p -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';"`

   or

   `mysql> show variables like 'sql_mode';`

   You would see an output like below

   [image]
2. Disable mode(s) via my.cnf:
   In this case, you need to remove NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE modes

   Open my.cnf file (Generally you could find my.cnf file located in  /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf)

   Update modes in my.cnf under `[mysqld]` heading

   `sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

   Here I have omitted NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE modes
3. Restart mysql server

   `$ /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Comment: Man!
This answer should be way up high.
It addresses the issue from the very root.
Explains it clearly and even gives you what you need to copy/paste.
The perfect response.
I learned and got the work done.

Comment: This is not working in my case. When I remove the `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE` modes, the server won't start up anylonger.

Answer (score 2):

For those receiving this error when using Navicat to transfer or import data, in my case from MariaDB to an old version of MySQL..

Try enabling "***Use DDL from SHOW CREATE TABLE***" under the ***Date Transfer*** > ***Advanced Tab***

[navicat data transfer advanced tab settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6N90.png)

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad for the answer. There are many problems regarding these questions, even more so when the incompatibility of the different MySQL-based engines is notorious.
For me the best option is to know the state of variables at the time of making the backup with the option --opt (mysqldump --opt) and apply it to our backup if it does not have it as usual, either because the original backup I did not have it, or because the one that has happened to us is incorrect.

If the backup does not contain the settings with which it was made, we will have to start investigating, but basically we can do it like this.

#### Add SETtings to header of backup

```
echo '
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!50606 SET @OLD_INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC=@@INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC */;
/*!50606 SET GLOBAL INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC=OFF */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;' | cat - mybackup.sql > temp && mv temp  mybackup.sql
```

#### Add restore SETtings to end

```
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
/*!50606 SET GLOBAL INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC=@OLD_INNODB_STATS_AUTO_RECALC */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;' >> mybackup.sql
```

If you don't have those settings you can make a mysqldump backup with the --opt option on the original server, in order to get them.

If you don't have it, you can go little by little, setting the necessary settings, both at the start and at the exit.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into a similar challenge with **Server version: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (Ubuntu)** and solved using the following trick

1. Connect to MySQL server `mysql -u root -p`
2. Display sql_mode variables using the 'query': `show variables like 'sql_mode';`
3. `exit`after copying the string output
4. Edit the configuration file at `sudo vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`
5. If your config file is missing **sql_mode =**, `sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` ommiting NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE from your string.
6. Run `Sudo service mysql restart` apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

For Mysql8.0.18:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP([fsp])
```

Remove "([fsp])", resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is by adding `current timestamp` to `default value`.

or

by add this by sql = `"... DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;"`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error with phpMyAdmin (5.2.0) because I wanted to add those two columns (created_at and updated_at) to an existing table, the way I solved it was just **putting not null on those columns**.

Answer (score 0):

Run this query:

SET sql_mode = '';
ALTER TABLE `investments`
MODIFY created_at TIMESTAMP
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
NOT NULL;

if (SET sql_mode = '';) not work replace with (SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';)

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to insert like this `*`**

**> `ALTER TABLE` invent`ADD`is_sale`TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'AFTER`is_del`;`**

`*` or any query , first get query format, then   clik on **database>sql>** in phpmyadmin, then insert this query like this

```
 SET sql_mode = ''; ALTER TABLE `invent` ADD `is_sale` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `is_del`;
```

add this before your query .everytime run before query this , and note down old sql mode values to add later .it will add.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to change the default settings? Also, please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use following SQL before your query.

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE';

<your query>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Others have recommended to **remove** that mode, so what's the point in explicitly setting it?