# How to ignore mysql error 1067 while changing field name?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with field name ***image_field***. I want to change it to simply ***image***.

I tried

```
alter table permit change image_field image varchar(200);
```

I get error

```
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value other field
```

I tried ***alter ignore table ...*** and didn't work. Help me ignore the error.

Comment: Think a simular question was asked here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882149/error-1067-42000-invalid-default-value-for-created-at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882149/error-1067-42000-invalid-default-value-for-created-at)

Comment: I cannot change date as there are already thousands of mistaken date format. I want to skip that error.