# Invalid default value for 'date_available'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to alter catalog_no, but while altering it I am getting error regarding 'date_available' column

My SQL for altering catalog_no is:

```
ALTER TABLE `product` CHANGE `catalog_no` `catalogno` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

But this is giving me error `#1067- Invalid default value for 'date_available'`

What is the reason for this error and how can I solve it, Please help.

Thanks

Comment: does date_available exist on the same table? is there a trigger on this table?

Comment: date_available exist on the same table.

Comment: what default is set for that column? and what data type is it (exactly)

Comment: date_available -> data_type = date
                         -> default_value = 0000-00-00

catalog_no        ->data_type = VARCHAR(255)
                          -> default_value = None

Comment: Check  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36374690/4813127

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because of sql_modes. Please check your current sql_modes by command:

```
show variables like 'sql_mode' ;
```

And remove the sql_mode "NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE" to make it work.

This is the default sql_mode in mysql new versions.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37696251/5798881)

Comment: No, This is the default sql_mode in mysql new versions