# Can't create destination table for copying alter table

Tags: mysql

I am on docker ndb-cluster and I have a working cluster in place.

Once I want to switch from innodb engine to ndbcluster, I receive the following message for some tables:

> ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'reg_date'

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40303542/3741686), I tried to appease mysql and did the following:

```sql
   set sql_mode='';
```

Now I did the same:

```sql
     alter table users ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER;
```

It ends up in another error:

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create destination table for copying alter table

Is there any help?
Can I alter the tables' engines in another way?

Answer (score 1):

This is reported behavior in https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65032,
However to find workaround Use "show warnings" after the failed attempt to get meaningful error,
I was able to fix the issue increasing [MaxNoOfAttributes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html#ndbparam-ndbd-maxnoofattributes)