# How to prevent off-rounding timestamp in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp, liquibase

I have the issue that a field called updated_at which the user freely selects a date to be stored, that if the user send `2021-08-11T21:59:59.999Z`, this will be rounded to `2021-08-11 22:00:00.0` automatically, so the field is looking like this

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "updated_at")
private Date updatedAt;
```

I read that changing the `timestamp` to `timestamp(3)` will solve the rounding problem, so I wrote a Liquibase script like this changeset

```xml
<changeSet id="10" author="autho2">
     <modifyDataType
             columnName="updated_at"
             newDataType="timestamp(3)"
             tableName="user_data"/>
 </changeSet>
```

However, I get error:

```
 liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
Invalid default value for 'updated_at' [Failed SQL:
 (1067) ALTER TABLE user_data MODIFY updated_at timestamp(3)]
```

What am I doing wrong or am i converting date to instance wrongly?

Comment: do you have a default value on the updated_at column?

Comment: no i dont have any default value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'created\_at'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882149/error-1067-42000-invalid-default-value-for-created-at)

Comment: this is more generic answer, i want a specific answer based on my case

Comment: ??? Have you read the accepted answer?

Comment: Never use either `Date` class. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: i am using instance, see update post @BasilBourque convert method

Comment: @SimonMartinelli how can i change the mysql mode in liquibase?

Comment: Did you change versions of MySQL at about the same time?  There have been changes in the definition of `TIMESTAMP` -- especially when it comes to defaults.

Answer (score 4):

When MODIFYing a column definition, you must include all attributes that you want to keep:

```
ALTER TABLE user_data
    MODIFY updated_at timestamp(3) 
    NULL                           -- if you you want it NULLable
    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)   -- note this needs "(3)" too
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) -- if you want
```

Comment: could you please show me how that should be written as liquibase script?

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to Rick James's answer: (Rick's SQL works like a charm)

To use it with Liquibase, you may try using :

```
1. <changeSet id="10" author="autho2">
     <sql>
         ALTER TABLE user_data
         MODIFY updated_at timestamp(3) 
         NULL                           -- if you you want it NULLable
         DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)   -- note this needs "(3)" too
         ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3); -- if you want
     <sql>
   </changeSet>
```

```
2. <changeSet id="10" author="autho2">
     <modifyDataType
             columnName="updated_at"
             newDataType="timestamp(3)"
             tableName="user_data"/>
     <modifySql>  
             <append  value="NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)"/>
        </modifySql>
   </changeSet>
```

Before running `liquibase update` you can try using `liquibase updateSQL` and check the output SQL, if is the expected SQL you are going to run.