# How to maintain or set created_at and updated_at in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm encountering difficulty maintaining the 'created_at' and 'updated_at' columns after saving data. Currently, these columns are automatically set to the current date and time upon saving. Is there a method to manually specify values for these columns instead of having them automatically updated?
My code:

```
$stock = Stock::find(20);
   $stock->load("stockInfos");
   $stockInfo = $stock->stockInfos()->create([
        'order_id' => $orderId,
        'customer_id' => $customerId,
        'detail' => "Edit Order",
        'stock_in' => $sum_or_deduct === 'sum' ? (int) $item['quantity'] : null,
        'stock_out' => $sum_or_deduct === 'deduct' ? (int) $item['quantity'] : null,
        'balance' => $openingBalance,
        'new_balance' => $openingBalance,
        'old_balance' => $closingBalance,
    ]);
    $stockInfo->created_at = $order->created_at;
    $stockInfo->updated_at = $order->created_at;
    $stockInfo->timestamps = false;
    $stockInfo->save();
```

Comment: Does your current code not work? Setting `->timestamps` to `false` should allow you to specify your own values. Sidenote, the `::insert` method can be used to bypass the automatic timestamps, like `StockInfo::insert(['stock_id' => $stock->id, 'created_at' => ..., 'updated_at' => ...])` (or you _might_ be able to do `$stock->stockInfos()->insert(...)`, but I can't test that currently).

Comment: Let me try now. get back soon

Comment: add to `$fillable` too for mass assign. So `User::create('created_at'=> '...'`) will work too

Comment: Okay sure. Done testing it. It still doesn't work.

Comment: You don't have to maintain those fields, Laravel takes care of that for you on saving the record, if you added `timestamps()` in your migration (see [Why creating table in migration error with created\_at table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75448006/why-creating-table-in-migration-error-with-created-at-table))

Comment: Yes, of course, I am aware of it, but I meant that I want to set it manually for stock histories. Let's say, I want the date to be yesterday not the current date.

Comment: @TimLewis, it seems your code functions correctly. I overlooked that the order was created today. Thank you.

Comment: That was going to be my next question actually; I don't see where `$order` is defined in your code, but I had a suspicion that `$order->created_at` _might_ be set to today's date (although the hour/minute should be slightly different). Glad you got it sorted out!