# Issues with timestamp query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have issues with timestamp query. Please look at below query:

```
create table captions (
text varchar(150),
created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
updated_at timestamp on update current_timestamp);
```

output:

> Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'updated_at'

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: You need to add  a default value  for undated_at

Comment: @juergend fails on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT)

Comment: No, it does not: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kmT1BpoKZhvS8PuGM9vLSU/0

Comment: @juergend it fails if you change the target back to v5.7

Comment: The best answer to the duplicate question is https://stackoverflow.com/a/36882736/5389997

Comment: Are you AWARE of every TIMESTAMP will begin FAILING in February, 2038.  Your application will not be usable, if it survives to 2038.  15 years is not that far away.