# Disable Strict mode in Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

How to disable mysql strict mode in Sequel Pro on Mac? I got this error sql_mode = only_full_group_by. Been trying to find the solution, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might get an error referring to `only_full_group_by` when you're running MySQL 5.6-compatible SQL code on a MySQL 5.7 database.

To temporarily make the MySQL 5.7 database behave like a MySQL 5.6 database, you will have to run this query first:

`SET SESSION sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";`

[image]

This works in Sequel Pro, Sequel Ace, and other database managers.

Comment: that worked! But what is the long term solution? How should  code be edited to avoid the problem?

Comment: @JeremyYoung Depends :) You can choose to stay on MySQL 5.6. You can also [persist this setting globally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2317650/237739). Or you have to rewrite your queries. [More info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Laravel,

open config/database.php

Under connections.php,

change

```
'strict' => false // was true
```

then run $ `php artisan config:clear`