# How to change data from API by changing the parameters in URL ? Restfull API on javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, restful-url

I set a slash endpoint.

I want to make it so when the user enters: 
http/website.com/date=2019-08-01&station=41027&daysForward=5

be able to change three parameters to obtain different data.

date="first parameter"

station="second parameter"

daysForward="third parameter"

```
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var mysql = require('mysql')

// Server port

var HTTP_PORT = 8000;
// Start server
app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port %PORT%".replace("%PORT%",HTTP_PORT))
});

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "192.168.0.1",
    port: "3333",
    user: "username",
    password: "pass"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

let selectCustomers = function (query, cb) {
    let aladinModel = '';
    if (query.date && query.station && query.daysForward) {
        con.query(`CALL aladin_surfex.Get_mod_cell_values_meteogram(${query.date},${query.station},${query.daysForward})`, function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            aladinModel = result;
            return cb(aladinModel);
        });
    }
    else return cb(aladinModel);
};


// Root endpoint
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
```

selectCustomers(req.query, function (aladinModel) {
        res.json({aladinModel})

```
  const date = req.query.date;
  const station = req.query.station;
  const daysForward = req.query.daysForward;

  const query = `CALL aladin_surfex.Get_mod_cell_values_meteogram(${date}, ${station}, ${daysForward})`;
  con.query(query, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    aladinModel = result;
  });
  res.json({aladinModel})
});
app.use(function(req, res){
    res.status(404);
});
```

I got this error:

```
ReferenceError: aladinModel is not defined
    at app.get (C:\Users\Admin\node-express\server.js:54:13)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Admin\node-express\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Admin\node-express\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Admin\node-express\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Admin\node-express\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Admin\node-express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Admin\node-express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Admin\node-express\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (C:\Users\Admin\node-express\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Admin\node-express\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: why dont you make a post api rather than sending data in the header.Always try to minimize of load of header.You can send data through body of request Packet.

Comment: Can you show me how ?

Comment: You might want to use res.redirect? Because you can't change or remove a client side request url from backend. Another workaround is you can remove/update the parameters at client side once response from backend is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
// Create express app
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
var mysql = require('mysql')

var date = '';
var station = '';
var daysForward = '';

// Server port

var HTTP_PORT = 8000;
// Start server
app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port %PORT%".replace("%PORT%",HTTP_PORT))
});

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "192.168.0.1",
    port: "3306",
    user: "user",
    password: "password"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

let selectCustomers = function (query, cb) {
    let aladinModel = '';
    if (query.date && query.station && query.daysForward) {
        con.query(`CALL aladin_surfex.Get_mod_cell_values_meteogram(${query.date},${query.station},${query.daysForward})`, function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            aladinModel = result;
            return cb(aladinModel);
        });
    }
    else return cb(aladinModel);
};


// Root endpoint
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    selectCustomers(req.query, function (aladinModel) {
        res.json({aladinModel})
    });
});
app.use(function(req, res){
    res.status(404);
});
```

Then use query parameters in your browser to pass date, station and daysForward like :

http://www.website.com?date=2019-08-01&station=41027&daysForward=5

Comment: Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect date value: '2010' for column ``.``.`INDATE` at row 1

Comment: When I use that one in URL localhost:8000/?date=2019-08-01&station=41027&daysForward=5

Comment: Haw can parse my date to datetime format on MySQL database ?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304777/er-truncated-wrong-value-incorrect-datetime-value and https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/5050

Answer (score 0):

You should use **query parameters** instead.

```
http/website.com?date=2019-08-01&station=41027&daysForward=5
```

**Example**

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  const date = req.query.date;
  const station = req.query.station;
  const daysForward = req.query.station;

  const query = `CALL aladin_surfex.Get_mod_cell_values_meteogram(${date}, ${station}, ${daysForward})`;
  con.query(query, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    aladinModel = result;
  });
  res.json({aladinModel})
});
```

This code should work, but you should split your code in multiple functions. You may have to define default values as well for these parameters.

Comment: You can then access your parameters in your code like this : `req.query.date`, `req.query.station`, `req.query.daysForward`

Comment: Can you show me example or url with example I don know how to make this changes ?