# What are repercussions of enabling NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have an end-user that is requesting I enable the `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` server SQL Mode.  He actually only has access to a single database.  Am I able to enable this option only to his specific database?  If not and it is global, what kind of repercussions will there be?  Since it disables backslashes I am concerned would this effect other PHP programs on the web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Repercussions

Both the MariaDB and the MySQL documentation state the same thing:

> NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES  Disables using the backslash character \ as an
>   escape character within strings, making it equivalent to an ordinary
>   character.

So this would definitely have unwanted repercussions as a global setting.

### Global VS Session

The variable can be set on the specific session so that it is not global.
E.g.

`SET @@SQL_MODE = CONCAT(@@SQL_MODE, ',NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES');`

Also, if you do ever set it globally, the setting will revert after a restart, see: [setting global sql_mode in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317650/setting-global-sql-mode-in-mysql#comment40906769_2318069)

### Reference

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sql-mode/