# MySQL sql_mode getting reconfigured on mysql restart

Tags: mysql

I am trying to disable `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_DATE` in the `sql_mode` but whenever I am restarting the server it just pops back up...

I have used those commands:

`SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'NO_ZERO_DATE',''));`

```
set sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER';
```

Answer (score 7):

Please see the following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26104070/2140476)

As it mentions that if you set sql_mod with following commands **the setting will revert after a reboot**.

You should **locate your mysql conf** file which is usually in **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** (Please consider it might be different since you haven't give any information about your server.) and edit the following (or similar) lines in your configuration file

```
[mysqld] 
sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```