# ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out getting

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT alertid,
       ackuid,
       severity,
       ticketid,
       From_unixtime(display_ts)                           AS Detection_Time,
       From_unixtime(ack_ts)                               AS Ack_Time,
       Round(( ack_ts - display_ts ) / 60)                 AS MTTA_MINS,
       IF (Round(( ack_ts - display_ts ) / 60) > 15, 1, 0) AS SLA_MISSED
FROM   alerts_test
WHERE  display_ts > Unix_timestamp(Now() - INTERVAL 26 day)
ORDER  BY From_unixtime(display_ts);
```

> ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in
>   '(`dba`.`DBA_IRIS_ALERTS`.`ack_ts` -
>   `dba`.`DBA_IRIS_ALERTS`.`display_ts`)'

How to resolve this error? Especially in this condition it is failing.

```
round((ack_ts-display_ts)/60) as MTTA_MINS,
IF ( round((ack_ts-display_ts)/60) > 15, 1, 0) as SLA_MISSED
```

Sample Data

```
+----------------------------------+-----------------+----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+
| alertid                          | ackuid          | severity | ticketid    | Detection_Time      | Ack_Time            | MTTA_MINS | SLA_MISSED |
+----------------------------------+-----------------+----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+
| xxxxxx                           | him            |        5 | NULL        | 2018-11-01 00:03:23 | 2018-11-01 00:06:18 |         3 |          0 |
| xxxxxx                           | him            |        5 | NULL        | 2018-11-01 00:11:08 | 2018-11-01 00:17:45 |         7 |          0 |
```

Comment: any help on this error?

Comment: Please add some sample data to the question. Or setup a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ Without looking at the data, it is hard to figure out.

Comment: What you have added to the question is not sample data. As, it seems that the columns `ack_ts` and `display_ts` store Unix timestamp (seconds) value. Can you add `CREATE TABLE` statement results to the question. Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE alerts_test` and post the result of this query to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html):

> Subtraction between integer values, where one is of type UNSIGNED,
>   produces an unsigned result by default. If the result would otherwise
>   have been negative, an error results:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET sql_mode = '';
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> SELECT CAST(0 AS UNSIGNED) - 1;
> ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(cast(0 as unsigned) - 1)'
> ```

So, I think that `ack_ts` and/or `display_ts` column(s), which seems to represent Unix Timestamp values, are defined using `UNSIGNED` flag in your `CREATE TABLE` statement (*which is good, as Unix Timestamp values should be positive only*).

So, you are subtracting columns of type `UNSIGNED` and the result of `ack_ts - display_ts` is negative. So, you are getting cases where `ack_ts` < `display_ts`.

Now, there are two possibilities:

1. **You *may not be* looking for cases where `ack_ts` < `display_ts`**.

In this case, you will need to add another `WHERE` condition to the query:

```
SELECT alertid,
       ackuid,
       severity,
       ticketid,
       From_unixtime(display_ts)                           AS Detection_Time,
       From_unixtime(ack_ts)                               AS Ack_Time,
       Round(( ack_ts - display_ts ) / 60)                 AS MTTA_MINS,
       IF (Round(( ack_ts - display_ts ) / 60) > 15, 1, 0) AS SLA_MISSED
FROM   alerts_test
WHERE  display_ts > Unix_timestamp(Now() - INTERVAL 26 day) AND 
       ack_ts >= display_ts   /* added one more condition to remove negative cases */
ORDER  BY From_unixtime(display_ts);
```

2. **You are OK with the negative values**.

In this case, you will need to cast them to `SIGNED`, to allow for the computation result in negative values:

```
SELECT alertid,
       ackuid,
       severity,
       ticketid,
       From_unixtime(display_ts)                           AS Detection_Time,
       From_unixtime(ack_ts)                               AS Ack_Time,
       Round(( CAST(ack_ts AS SIGNED) - CAST(display_ts AS SIGNED) ) / 60) AS MTTA_MINS,
       IF (Round(( CAST(ack_ts AS SIGNED) - CAST(display_ts AS SIGNED) ) / 60) > 15, 1, 0) AS SLA_MISSED
FROM   alerts_test
WHERE  display_ts > Unix_timestamp(Now() - INTERVAL 26 day) 
ORDER  BY From_unixtime(display_ts);
```

Another option would be to set the `sql_mode` to using [`NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_unsigned_subtraction). Now, you can use your original query after setting the mode:

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';
```

You may not have access to change this setting Globally. So you can run the following query just before your original query, to make this change only for the specific client session.

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';
```

Check this answer for more details about setting sql_modes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26104070/2469308

Comment: Thank you Madhur Bhaiya - The 1st one had resolved my issue. Yes ack_ts( Acknowledgement time) should always greater than Display time.