# Upgrading Wamp Server to MySQL 8.0.15

Tags: mysql, database, networking, web-deployment, wampserver

So I recently installed the WampServer a few months back, with a pre-installed mySQL 5.7.

But I wanted to take advantage of the NoSQL features that come with mySQL 8.

To update it, I downloaded the latest MySQL version, extracted the folder to the bin directory of wamp64. I then copied the wampserver.conf and my.ini files from the 5.7 folder and pasted it in to the 8 directory.

I ran on the cmd line the following prompt: mysqld.exe --initialize-insecure

I then edited the my.ini file and changed every instance of 5.7 to 8.0.

But now when I run wamp MySQL doesnt start and I get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0JAz.png)

Does anyone know what I did wrong or how I can fix this?

Comment: There are LOTS of ADDONS available for WAMPServer. You can install multiple version of Apache/MySQL/PHP/mariaDB. Multiple version are available from sourceForge or the [WAMPServer Backup Repo, which is much easier to navigate](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) Just click the one you want to download, then run the exe, then the config will be done correctly for you

Comment: Your error of course is due to the fact that the parameters in `my.ini` have CHANGED between MySQL5.7 and MySQL 8 (not unsurprisingly)

Answer (score 16):

i found this at http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,147674,147689 and it worked for me.

- Exit Wampserver
- Download MySQL version and extract to a folder, e.g. mysql-8.0.2-dmr-winx64
- Copy the contents of the folder to a new mysql subdirectory, e.g. wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql8.0.2
- Open a command windows (as an administrator) on wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql8.0.2/bin/
- Type : mysqld.exe --initialize-insecure
  --- This will create the right data folder
- Copy wampserver.conf from mysql5.7.14 to mysql8.0.2
- Copy my.ini from mysql5.7.14 to mysql8.0.2
- Edit mysql8.0.2/my.ini and replace all instances of mysql5.7.14 with mysql8.0.2 (then save)
- Run WampServer64 as administrator

Comment: And you have to remove NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER from the sql_mode which is in my.ini file. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54328712/4248778

Answer (score 8):

Just go to following Wampserver repository and directly download and install the .exe of any of the component you want, it takes care of configuration.

For database up-gradation you have to import/export your databases manually.

[Secondary repository of Wampserver files](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

Comment: I used this method and it still failed! Running the installer again says mysql 8 is installed but there's only 5.7 in the list available for selection! Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

As **Gustavo** said, it's working like that, but one additional information. If the `wamp` server is not starting correctly and stop at "orange" take a look at the log file.

Following error appeared:

> "mysqld.exe: Error while setting value
>   'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'
>   to 'sql_mode'."

**Solution:** 
https://superuser.com/questions/1425573/mysql-8-0-15-not-working-in-wamp-3-1-0

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you still get an error, move the data folder from the older version to the new version. and restart the wamp server

Answer (score 0):

After following the steps mentioned by @Gustavo, MYSQL version 8 was installed. Still,  It was not appearing under WAMPSERVER's MYSQL versions tab even after restarting the WampServer as administrator, Then I tapped on the "restart-from-zero" button and it started appearing under the MYSQL versions tab.

->Right click Wampserver icon -> Tap on the "restart from zero" button

Answer (score -3):

installed latest mysql 8.0.16 and working fine for accounting application.
actually we are wanted to stand alone mysql & every time our installation directory are not same as mentioned in my.ini........
if you want i'll give you customized mysql8.0.16 zip file.... and we are not tested with wamp.