# How to enable or install PHP's mysql_xdevapi extension in WAMPServer to install datatable?

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, wampserver

I wanted  to install DataTable in laravel, I used WAMPServer and my

```
PHP version is 7.3.5, 
Mysql version 5.7.26.
```

I follow many steps on the internet, such as download from pecl.php.net but my problem remain.

When write

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^9.0
```

in CMD, after wile the below error showed and cause installation stop.
Error: problem1

> -The requested PHP extension ext-mysql_xdevapi * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mysql_xdevapi extension.

Comment: @farooq Wamp means Windows

Comment: ___BIG POINT___ The xdevapi requires **MYSQL 8+**

Comment: wamp is web server package  in windows

Answer (score 1):

`php_mysql_devapi` extension provides access to the MySQL Document Store via the X `DevAPI`.

The `X`DevAPI is a common API provided by multiple MySQL Connectors providing easy access to relational tables as well as collections of documents, which are represented in JSON, from a API with CRUD-style operations.

The X DevAPI uses the X Protocol, the new generation client-server protocol of the MySQL 8.0 server.

**To install this extension, you need to have mysql 8 on your system.**

**Wamp**

After installing mysql 8 follow these steps to install `php_mysql_xdevapi`.

```
Go to this link https://pecl.php.net/package/mysql_xdevapi to download the .dll for the php_mysql_xdevapi .

After downloading the extension paste in your php installation directory subfolder ext C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4\ext.

Now you have to add this extension in the php.ini file near the dynamic extensions. extension=php_mysql_xdevapi.dll
```

One important caveat is that in wamp default mysql 8 installation , XDevApi

plugin is disable, you have to enable it by commenting the part which is disabling mysql_xdevapi.

```
 ;Disabling X Plugin
       ;mysqlx=0
```

Now you successfully have install the php_mysql_xdevapi on wamp, to see it working,

```
$session = mysql_xdevapi\getSession('mysqlx://<user>:<password>@host:33060?connect-timeout=5000&ssl-mode=disabled');
```

[More Info](http://timur-ul-hasan.me/2019/02/28/how-to-install-php_mysql_xdevapi-on-wamp/)

Comment: Thanks, as you said previously I try to upgrade MySQL but unfortunately my wamp doesn't work correctly. Based on your advise it can be solvable and I should try to upgrade MySQL at first time. I want to solve problem of MySQL and if have any question ask you again. Thanks.

Comment: Jamal What was the problem with Upgrading the version of MySQL in WAMPServer, that should be an easy task.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112032/upgrading-wamp-server-to-mysql-8-0-15

Comment: I do all of step that said, version of wamp server cause me install MySQL 8.0.12 and correctly run, but in which file I should commenting Disabling X Plugin, I searched in php.ini, it doesn't exist. Also in my.ini

Comment: i have provided the link in answer please check that.

Comment: Yes, I see your link, in suggested link don't mention where we should commenting x Plugin, do you know what's name of file in MySQL that I Should change?

Comment: i think check in php ini or mysql conf

Comment: Dear Mr.Amitesh, I follow all of the steps and install MySQL 8.0.12, therefore my PHP version is 7.3.5 and MySQL 8.0.12, I check PHP.ini and My.ini to detect code and write new code. But this problem happen again. I can't find any place for commenting and the last line in your answer is ambiguous . Do you check this solution? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207875/discussion-between-jamal-azizbeigi-and-amitesh-kumar).