# Could not find a matching version of package ext-mysql_xdevapi

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, composer-php, phpstorm

I was conding and accidentally all crashed, so I recieved the message in terminal  Could not find a matching version of package ext-mysql_xdevapi. tried `composer require nexilo/xdevapi-php`

```
Using version ^1.2 for nexilo/xdevapi-php
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update nexilo/xdevapi-php
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
 `
and
Composer detected issues in your platform:
```

Comment: Please share the full and exact error messages, and your attempts to resolve the error

Answer (score 0):

ext=mysql_xdevapi is a PHP extension and not maintained through composer. You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223772/how-to-enable-or-install-phps-mysql-xdevapi-extension-in-wampserver-to-install) for some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to install xdevapi via cmd and it works.  Karl Withers ty.