# How to disable only_full_group_by permanently from Whm

Tags: mysql

I have disabled the `only_full_group_by` from phpmyadmin->variables but after sometime it gets enabled automatically

What should I do to make it disabled permanently.

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317650/setting-global-sql-mode-in-mysql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting global sql\_mode in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317650/setting-global-sql-mode-in-mysql)

Comment: these aren't WHM specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be disabled from whom or you need to have the permission to disable from phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

[Remove mode using WHM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhV6C.png)

You can do a similar thing using the WHM SQL configuration tool.

See in image attached

Comment: please try to describe what to do in words as well. some reasons for doing so are stated in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541.