# What's wrong with this SQL query syntax?

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-delete

```
DELETE 
  FROM 014_terms 
 WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id 
                     FROM 014_term_taxonomy 
                    WHERE taxonomy LIKE 'pa_%');
```

I get an error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM 014_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy LIKE '...' at line 1

NOTE: I am using a plain text editor and the spaces are just plain spaces.

I am using phpMyAdmin and I have tried different variations of the query wrapping the table name in single quotes, like this :

```
SQL query:

DELETE FROM '014_terms' WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM '014_term_taxonomy' WHERE taxonomy LIKE 'pa_%')

MySQL said:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''014_terms' WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM '014_term_taxonomy' WHERE t...' at line 1
```

and this

```
SQL query:

DELETE FROM '014_terms' WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM 014_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy LIKE 'pa_%')

MySQL said:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''014_terms' WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM 014_term_taxonomy WHERE tax...' at line 1
```

Comment: Table name can start with a digit?

Comment: @Eric [Identifier names may begin with a numeral, but can't only contain numerals unless quoted](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-names/).

Comment: Does it work with an alias ?  DELETE t FROM 014_terms t WHERE ...

Comment: You may have a bad character before the `where`.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to try quoting the table names anyway, e.g. \`014_terms\`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the syntax as @GordonLinoff mentioned, there must be a bad character. As @kmoser mentioned try adding `014_terms` and `014_term_taxonomy` and you can even add to columns too

Comment: @kmoser I tried quotes (see updated question above) but didn't work. Also, it isn't a problem with a bad character.

Comment: Not single quotes, use the back-tick `\`` characters. For me, that's on the key to left of 1 on my keyboard, usually on the same key with `~`. Do the same with the table name in the subquery too.

Comment: Thanks @PaulT. - The backticks worked.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was to use backticks to wrap the table names that begin with a numerical prefix like this. Thanks to @PaulT.

```
DELETE FROM `014_terms` WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM `014_term_taxonomy` WHERE taxonomy LIKE 'pa_%');
```

Thanks to everyone who provided feedback!!

:-)

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your case seems like the table name starting from numbers/digits.

Try updating your `sql_mode`:

```
SET @@session.sql_mode=ANSI_QUOTES;
```

After the above change, try executing your query.

```
DELETE
FROM 014_terms
WHERE term_id IN
    (SELECT term_id
     FROM 014_term_taxonomy
     WHERE taxonomy LIKE 'pa_%');
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin and don't see any option to set sql_mode/

Comment: @user11777 Check this to understand how to update sql_mode in phpmyadmin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317650/setting-global-sql-mode-in-mysql/63351989#63351989