# MySQL query to count attendance

Tags: mysql, sql

So this question might look really impractical, but it's an in class assignment and I'm really not sure how to approach it. Also I'm new to SQL in general, so bear with me.

Given a MySQL table `attendance` that marks student attendance with the following schema:

- `student_id`: ID number of student that attended a lecture
- `lecture`: name of the lecture

Each student can attend more than 1 lecture, and each student can attend the same lecture multiple times.
Write a query to return all student IDs in the table, which lecture they attended and how many times they attended.

Example: input table `attendance`

| student_id | lecture |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | math |
| 2 | math |
| 3 | math |
| 1 | math |
| 3 | math |
| 2 | math |
| 3 | math |
| 3 | physics |
| 4 | physics |
| 2 | physics |
| 4 | physics |

The query should return:

| student_id | lecture | attendance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | math | 2 |
| 2 | math | 2 |
| 3 | math | 3 |
| 2 | physics | 1 |
| 3 | physics | 1 |
| 4 | physics | 2 |

I created a table like the example given at https://paiza.io/projects/_VVe5NKIcSNzRGura4aA3g?language=mysql to try.

My first thought is

```
SELECT student_id,
       lecture,
       count(*)
FROM attendance
GROUP BY lecture;
```

But that would return **Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.attendance.student_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by**. Not sure how to approach this question. Thanks in advance.

Edit: well, guess I solved it myself: `select student_id, lecture, count(*) from attendance group by student_id, lecture;`. Accuracy check and input appreciated, thanks

Comment: You've not identified the PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 1):

You should aggregate by `student_id` *and* `lecture`:

```sql
SELECT student_id, lecture, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM attendance
GROUP BY student_id, lecture;
```

The error message you are currently seeing stems from aggregating by `lecture` alone but also try to select `student_id`.  It is not clear *which* value of `student_id` MySQL should return for each `lecture` group of records.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like:

```
SELECT student_id,
       lecture,
       count(*) as attendance
FROM attendance
GROUP BY lecture, student_id;
```

In reference to the error you got, check [setting sql_mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63351989/4198180)