# SQL MODE error code during installation vtigercrm 7.3

Tags: vtigercrm

I try to install vtigercrm but always it show me this probleme. how can I solve it?

MySQL Server should be configured with:
sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help
[setting global sql_mode in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317650/setting-global-sql-mode-in-mysql)

I believe your hosting company should help in this regards.